# How to filter out the same log, only keep the 1st one until value changed?

Tags: sql, ranking

I would like to keep the row first added, if `CODE` is same as in the previous row (filter out newest added). The code may not show only one time. Therefore, it seems that I can not simply use `Qualify rank() over(partition by ...order by ...)` to get the result.

Here is the raw data:

```
id  START_DATE  CODE
--- ---------- -----
 1  2008-02-03   A
 1  2010-04-22   A
 1  2013-01-29   C
 1  2013-12-22   C
 1  2016-05-25   B
 1  2017-07-13   A
```

and the final result I look forward to:

```
id  START_DATE  CODE
--- ---------- -----
 1  2008-02-03   A
 1  2013-01-29   C
 1  2016-05-25   B
 1  2017-07-13   A
```

Are there any ways to get the result with SQL?

Comment: You should at least let us know which SQL database product you are using, as the various SQL dialects differ.

Comment: Why first two `A` rows are sequenced rows and last `A` row is separately? what defines order here? do you have some another unique identifier column?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which server you are on, you can use `LAG()` window function to test if the previous row has the same code, and if it does then flag it and keep only the one with the first date.

You can read more about `LAG()` window functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql). I think the syntax will be fairly alike for most servers supporting it.

Consider below script to get you the desired result (SQL Server):

```
select
    id
    ,START_DATE
    ,CODE 
from 
(
select 
    id
    ,START_DATE
    ,CODE 
    ,CASE WHEN CODE = LAG(CODE) over (order by id, START_DATE asc) THEN 0 else 1 END as flag
from 
    YOURTABLE as T
) as T
where
    flag = 1
```

Comment: That's not specific to SQL Server. Oracle, Postgres, DB2, Teradata, Informix, Vertica, Ingres, Firebird and Redshift support window functions as well. Actually most of them supported lag() long before SQL Server did

Comment: I only know SQL Server and Teradata, therefore I wanted to put in the disclaimer to not "upset" anyone in case that functionality wasn't available anywhere else, resulting in downvotes ;-)

Comment: it seems that LAG() function not work in Teradata, but I'm able to replace it with "MAX(CODE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY START_DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING )" to get the previous value

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
select 
    id, [START_DATE], CODE
from (
    select *
      --, lag(CODE) over (order by id, [START_DATE]) as prevCODE
      --  ^^^^ for non-supported languages use below code instead vvvv
        , (select top(1) tt.CODE -- if `top(1)` not supported may you need to add `limit 1` afyer order by
           from t tt 
           where tt.id = t.id and tt.[START_DATE] > t.[START_DATE] 
            order by tt.[START_DATE]
          ) prevCODE
    from t
    ) t1
where 
    CODE <> coalesce(prevCODE, '');
```

[`[SQL Server Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49913f/2)
[`[MySQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/463888/3)

Comment: In your SQL Server Fiddle you need to reverse the order in your `LEAD` or use `LAG` because you give him newest results rather than oldest (as per his description).

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen tnx; my miss understanding ;).